# Override Objective-C class method with "new" prefix in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have a problem with overriding class method from Objective-C in Swift. I can invoke it from Swift no problem but not override it.

Method signature:

```
+ (id<MyInterface>)newObjectWithId:(NSString *)objectId properties:(NSDictionary *)properties andClient:(Client *)client;
```

Class hierarchy:

```
NSObject <-- MyObject1 <-- MyObject2 <-- MySwiftClass
```

`MyObject1` declares and implements aforementioned method and so does `MyObject2`. However trying to override it in Swift does not work. It is not visible in autocompletion and when I write it manually it says `Method does not override any method from its superclass`. Signature I wrote looks like this:

```
override class func newObjectWithId(objectId: String!, properties: NSDictionary!, andClient client: Client!) -> MyInterface
```

I did overriding for some other class methods in this class too and they work without a problem. I assume it's a problem with `new` prefix in this method. Has anyone  encountered something like this and resolved it successfully?

Comment: You have transposed 'object' and 'with' in the swift function. It should be `newObjectWithId` not `newWithObjectId`

Comment: Corrected but this not make issue go away. :(